# while loop output with delay

Tags: php

i am using while loop to display last 30 albums thumbnail but as you know 30 photo at once will slow down webpage loading time si i want once the webpage is completely loaded i want to load these 30 photo in interval of 5 seconds. first 5 photo will be loaded after 5 seconds of webpage is fully loaded then again after gap of 5 seconds next 5 photo will be loaded i know i can do this with 6 query but why to waste server resources so i want one query but loading as per users convenient.here is my while loop

```
     $res = mysql_query("SELECT * from `"tableA where cat='photos' order by created desc limit 30");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $photo .= thumbnail($row,150);
        }
```

after that whereever i want i can call $photo

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is with javascript (and jQuery for extra ease). Check out this [Lazy Loading](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) jQuery plugin for example.

Answer (score 1):

You should output some markup that contains either the URLs of the images or data from which Javascript can recreate the URLs, and then, on the client side you may handle creating images from that markup on the fly, with delays and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. I also fixed the quotes in your query a bit..

```
<?php
$round =1; 
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * from `tableA` where `cat`='photos' order by created desc limit 30");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) 
    {
        $photo .= thumbnail($row,150);
        if (($round % 5) == 0 ) { // action only happens when round is divisble by 5
            sleep(5); // wait 5 seconds
        }
        $round += 1;
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: i was thinking something like this let me check whether it works or not

Comment: all photos are being loaded without any delay

Comment: I've been looking through the answers.. I think some of the commenters are right.. You might need a front-end way to do this..

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the page is displayed to the user only AFTER all PHP were executed so you can't count on PHP to delay some display.

As already mentionned you'll have to do it client side (probably in Javascript).
A way would be to construct (using PHP) a Javascript array containing all your image URL and then loop through this array with appropriate delay.

The server side will look like this : (EDIT : assuming tableA contains a column named 'url')

```
$images = array();
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * from `tableA` where cat='photos' order by created desc limit 30");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $images[] = $row['url'];
}
echo json_encode($images);
```